# less.vim not working on my Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, vim, less

I found many sites saying that `vim` can be used as a pager like `less` with syntax highlighting.

So to make it work I added this line to my `.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias vless='vim -u /usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.vim'
```

but when I run something like

```
ps -A | vless
```

It gives this output and exits without showing me the output of `ps`:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Please help!

Comment: Related: [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The above command `vim -u /usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.vim` is not handling input from STDIN correctly. However, opening a file with the above works just fine.

Fortunately the Vim installation provides a shell script `less.sh` which loads `less.vim` and handles the case where input is from STDIN correctly. So changing the alias to this works:

```
alias vless = '/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh'
```